# App Script Code for a Data Base creation to Google Workspace

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-workspace

I have apps script code to create a Data Base that is currently being used in Google Sheets. I cant seem to find any help on the internet on how to Edit the code to be able to run on Google Workspace. I have added "Area120Tables" and the "Sheets" Services added. I will include my current app script code that is working for my sheets Data Base.

```
var server = web.server;
var dbName = web.dbName;
var username = web.username;
var password = web.password;
var port = web.port;
var url = web.url;


    
function createConnction() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, username, password);
  Logger.log(conn)
  conn.close();
}

function create_Db() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, username, password);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("DataBase");
  //sheet.getRange('A5:X400').clearContent();
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  //remove the set filter if one exist
  //  removeFilter();

  stmt.setMaxRows(500);
  
  var results = stmt.executeQuery('(SELECT  housemaster.address1 as Address,date_format(housemaster.ratified_date, "%m/%d/%Y") as Ratified_Date, ' 
  + ' CONCAT(LEFT(housemaster.homephone,3),"-", MID(housemaster.homephone,4,3),"-", RIGHT(housemaster.homephone,4)) as Phone, '
      + ' (CASE WHEN housemaster.conststart_date is Null OR (DateDiff(housemaster.conststart_date,housemaster.contract_date)) >= 0 Then "NO" ELSE "YES" END) AS Spec, '
      + ' CONCAT(prospectmaster.firstname, " ",  prospectmaster.lastname) as Name, '
      + ' (CASE WHEN housemaster.estsettl_date IS NULL then date_format(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(housemaster.ratified_date), INTERVAL +1 DAY), INTERVAL +6 MONTH),"%m/%d/%Y") ELSE housemaster.estsettl_date END) AS ClosingDate, '
      + ' DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(housemaster.ratified_date), INTERVAL +1 DAY), INTERVAL +6 MONTH) , "%Y") AS ClosingYear, '
      //+ ' (CASE WHEN (housemaster.companycode) = '001' AND (devmaster.developmentcode) = '34' THEN '003' ELSE housemaster.companycode END) AS Company_Code, '
      + ' devmaster.developmentcode, housemaster.lotnumber, elevationmaster.squarefootage as Plan, housemaster.elevationcode, devmaster.description as Community, housemaster.baseprice as BasePrice, '
      + ' housemaster.baseprice+housemaster.optionsprice+housemaster.lotpremium+ housemaster.promissoryamt1+ housemaster.promissoryamt2+ prospectmaster.otheramt3+ housemaster.upgradeprice as TotalPrice, '
      + ' prospectmaster.optiondeposit, " " AS ListDate, salespersonmast.salespersoncode AS Sales, CONCAT(salespersonmast.firstname, " ",  salespersonmast.lastname) as SalesPersonName, '
      + ' CONCAT(prospectfinance.loanofficer, "/", prospectfinance.lendercode) AS LenderBank, CONCAT(agentmaster.agentname, "/", brokermaster.brokername) AS RealtorBroker,      "" as PossibleCAN, housemaster.misc1_field AS Status,  DATE_FORMAT(housemaster.contract_date, "%m/%d/%Y") AS contract_date, '
      + ' DATE_FORMAT(housemaster.ratified_date, "%m/%d/%Y") AS ratified_date, '
      + ' DATE_FORMAT((CASE WHEN housemaster.settlement_date IS NULL then " " ELSE housemaster.settlement_date END), "%m/%d/%Y") as settlement_date '
 + ' FROM ((((((housemaster INNER JOIN prospectmaster ON (housemaster.developmentcode = prospectmaster.developmentcode) '
 + ' AND (housemaster.companycode = prospectmaster.companycode) '
 + ' AND (housemaster.housenumber = prospectmaster.housenumber)) INNER JOIN elevationmaster ON (housemaster.companycode = elevationmaster.companycode) AND (housemaster.developmentcode = elevationmaster. developmentcode) '
 + ' AND (housemaster.modelcode = elevationmaster.modelcode) AND (housemaster.elevationcode = elevationmaster.elevationcode)) INNER JOIN modelmaster ON (elevationmaster.modelcode = modelmaster.modelcode) '
 + ' AND (elevationmaster.companycode = modelmaster.companycode)) INNER JOIN devmaster ON (elevationmaster.developmentcode = devmaster.developmentcode) AND (elevationmaster.companycode = devmaster.companycode)) '
 + ' INNER JOIN companymaster ON (prospectmaster.companycode = companymaster.companycode) AND (prospectmaster.companycode = companymaster.companycode)) '
 + ' INNER JOIN salespersonmast ON (housemaster.companycode = salespersonmast.companycode) AND (housemaster.salesmancode = salespersonmast.salespersoncode)) '
 + ' LEFT JOIN prospectconting ON prospectmaster.casenumber = prospectconting.casenumber '
 + ' LEFT JOIN prospectfinance ON prospectmaster.casenumber = prospectfinance.casenumber '
 + ' LEFT JOIN agentmaster ON (prospectmaster.BROKERCODE = agentmaster.brokercode) AND (prospectmaster.AGENTCODE = agentmaster.agentcode) '
 + ' LEFT JOIN brokermaster ON agentmaster.brokercode = brokermaster.brokercode '
 + ' INNER JOIN udprospectmst ON (prospectmaster.casenumber = udprospectmst.casenumber) '
 + ' GROUP BY housemaster.companycode, housemaster.contract_date, housemaster.ratified_date, housemaster.settlement_date, housemaster.address1 '
 + ' HAVING ( housemaster.companycode="005" ) and housemaster.baseprice > 0 '
 + ' ORDER by housemaster.companycode, housemaster.address1);')
 
 var numCols = results.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
 
  
  var values = [];
  while (results.next()) {
    var temp = [];
      for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
      temp.push(results.getString(col + 1))
    }
    values.push(temp);
  }
  Logger.log(values)
 
  results.close();
  stmt.close();
    
  sheet.getRange('A1:X400').clearContent();
  
   
  // var time = new Date(time);
  // var now = new Date();
  // var settime = 'Last Updated: ' + now  
  // SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A4').setValue(settime);
  
  sheet.getRange(5, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  results.close  //Edit: does this require ()?
 }
```

Comment: The code included currently works and is being used for Google sheets, I cant seem to find any documentation or forums to  convert it to work on workspace.

Comment: its also know as Google tables

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by `convert it to work on workspace`? Which specific [Google workspace product](https://developers.google.com/workspace/products#google_workspace_developer_products) are you trying to run your existing code?

Comment: currently the code is running on google sheets, I know I must change the code to be compatible with Google Tables so that it may be used as a trigger Bot.

Comment: It looks to me that you can import the data directly from the sheet and create the trigger bot inside of google tables.  No code is required. BTW I know a little more than a miniscule amount about google apps script.  Google Tables looks like an interactive tool which minimizes the need for scripting.   It's probably not something I'll ever spend much time with.  This is the first time I ever seen a question on it on this forum

Comment: The Data isnt coming from a sheet its coming from a SQL Data Base, If you look at the code and see the QUERY statements. Hence why the code is needed in App script. If your answer was to just use the same DataBase sheet created now and import it over that would defeat the purpose of using Google Tables to cut back on mass Google Sheets.

Comment: I know but now that you have put it into a table you can import that into google tables.  The Google Tables API doesn't seem to give Apps Script anything but editing access to workspaces and tables that already exist within Google Tables.

Comment: Perhaps a future realease of the API will give google apps script greater access to creation of work spaces and tables but I don't see it in there now.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the Google Tables API and looked pretty closely and it's features and you can get and list in Workspaces and Tables but there's no create.  So if you can't create tables and workspaces how are you planning on create tables from a database.

The current release of tables is a beta and there are apparently plans to expand it in the future but I don't know what that includes.